# What Is The Best Order To Learn Beginner To Advanced Flutter Material?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm in the process of learning to become a better Flutter developer. I've taken a couple of intro courses on Udemy, and I've even built/released my first app.

While building my app, I realized I don't understand architecture.

My ultimate goal is to learn how to build apps as a professional developer would.

In the countless hours of research I've done, I've realized that professional developers:

- Separate code into layers (ie. Presentation, Domain, Data)
- Write their own tests
- Likely a list of other things I don't know yet
  understand.

While trying to learn these materials, I continually face the same problem. Every time I try to learn something new, I encounter something I don't understand.

For example, I might be trying to learn an architectural pattern, and out of the blue, I read terms like "dependency injection," "lazy singleton," or "repository." Because I have no idea what those things are, I get stuck.

I've tried to dig into the source code of professional apps, but it's way over my head. There's a massive gap between "I finished a couple of Udemy courses" and "I work as a senior engineer."

So, if you're an advanced developer, I have three questions.

1. If you had to teach a complete beginner to become a professional flutter developer, what material would you have them learn?
2. What reputable resources would you use to teach each topic?
3. In what order would you teach the material—to ensure the student could understand each new topic?

I know this is a broad question, so I'll narrow the scope. Ideally, I want to build apps like the team at Very Good Ventures does. For context, they use flutter_bloc, a Presentation, Domain, and Data type architecture (see picture), and write their own tests. And, as I mentioned above, likely a list of other things I don't yet understand :)

[Architecture Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDQjR.png)

Finally, I know I probably sound lazy. I certainly could read a million articles in an attempt to piece everything together. But, ideally, I was hoping to find a more effective path. So, that's why I'm asking the experts.

Thank you for your time,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using GPT3 and codex. Give them  all of the context you have, and ask your question. They have already read all of those articles plus looked at a lot of code. Because flutter is so new probably it is likely less represented in the data sets. However, I have been able to ask some forter questions and receive answers.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter can be best thought by flutter's creators, no other resources can teach you better,
Just follow flutter official documentation,
All the examples are carefully designed with best coding practices and patterns,

https://docs.flutter.dev/